# How to design undo function in Core-Graphics Framework?

Tags: core-graphics, restore, cgcontext, undo

Many pepole recommended that I save the image which I've just drawn, and load it when I need undo in the current picture.

But I think that may not be a good way to do this:

1. save and load to disk will cause lagging.
2. You cant erase after you undo, because you cant erase the image (not fill with backGroundColor).

So, I'm seeking for a way to restore the CGLayer's or context's data which is to cover the current one as "draw resource", when you need undo. I've used NSMutableData to do this, but its doesn't work at all, because only the pointer has been saved.

And I don't understand how to use CGContextSaveState,CGContextRestoreState. When you save it, you have to restore it before the drawRect has been done, you can't save it and restore when you need undo, because the context will be destroyed or reset when drawRect has done, and with all that I've tried, nothing happens.

Could somebody help me here? Thx!